# boost:asio thread pool implementation for occasionally synchronized tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, boost, boost-asio

I have a "main" function that performs many small, independent tasks each once per time step. However, after each time step, I must wait for all of the tasks to complete before stepping forward.

I want to make the program multithreaded. I have tried implementations with the boost-offshoot threadpool, and I've tried using a vector of (shared pointers to) threads, and I've tried the asio threadpool ideas (using an io_service, establishing some work, then distributing run to the threads and posting handlers to the io_service).

All of these seem to have a lot of overhead creating and destroying threads for my "many small tasks," and I want a way, preferably using the asio tools, to instantiate one io_service, one thread_group, posting handlers to the io_service, and waiting for a single time step's work to be finished before posting more tasks. Is there a good way to do this? Here's (stripped down) code for what I have working now:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
for(int theTime = 0; theTime != totalTime; ++theTime)
{
    io_service.reset();
    boost::thread_group threads;
    // scoping to destroy the work object after work is finished being assigned
    {
        boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxNumThreads; ++i)
        {
            threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
                &io_service));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numSmallTasks; ++i)
        {
            io_service.post(boost::bind(&process_data, i, theTime));
        }
    }
    threads.join_all(); 
}
```

Here's what I had rather have (but don't know how to implement):

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::thread_group threads;
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
for (int i = 0; i < maxNumThreads; ++i)
{
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
         &io_service));
}

for(int theTime = 0; theTime != totalTime; ++theTime)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numSmallTasks; ++i)
    {
        io_service.post(boost::bind(&process_data, i, theTime));
    }
    // wait here until all of these tasks are finished before looping 
    // **** how do I do this? *****
}
// destroy work later and join all threads later...
```

Comment: This is not as simple as calling io_service.stop() inside the "time" for loop, after all the tasks have been posted, is it? The docs don't seem to indicate that all posted handlers will be executed before stopping...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use [futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) for data processing and synchronize with them using [`boost::wait_for_all()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.wait_for_all). This will allow you to operate in terms of parts of work done, not threads.

```
int process_data() {...}

// Pending futures
std::vector<boost::unique_future<int>> pending_data;

for(int i = 0; i < numSmallTasks; ++i)
{
   // Create task and corresponding future
   // Using shared ptr and binding operator() trick because
   // packaged_task is non-copyable, but asio::io_service::post requires argument to be copyable

   // Boost 1.51 syntax
   // For Boost 1.53+ or C++11 std::packaged_task shall be boost::packaged_task<int()>
   typedef boost::packaged_task<int> task_t;

   boost::shared_ptr<task_t> task = boost::make_shared<task_t>(
      boost::bind(&process_data, i, theTime));

   boost::unique_future<int> fut = task->get_future();

   pending_data.push_back(std::move(fut));
   io_service.post(boost::bind(&task_t::operator(), task));    
}

// After loop - wait until all futures are evaluated
boost::wait_for_all(pending_data.begin(), pending_data.end());
```

Comment: Ok, this is sounding promising. I need to look into futures. Thank you for pointing me in this new direction.

Comment: Rost, I'm having trouble implementing this without std::move (I'm stuck on a C++03 compiler). How do I get around using std::move?

Comment: @JohnDoe Try to use `boost::move` instead

Comment: Instead of `std::unique_ptr` use `std::auto_ptr` in C++03, its copy constructor is actually a move constructor in C++03

Comment: Ok, I've gotten halfway there... I used a shared_future instead for the std::vector (and the copy constructor for shared_future from task.get_future()). But I can't for the life of me figure out how to post a packaged_task to the io_service (time for a new question). This seems like the right way to go, so I'll mark yours as the best answer. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: New question is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157502/how-do-you-post-a-boost-packaged-task-to-an-io-service-in-c03). Thanks @Rost for getting me on this path.

Comment: @Rost Maybe I am missing something here but I am currently facing problems which made me stumble upon this. Did you try to compile your code? `std/boost::packaged_task`s are uncopyable and unassignable and as `io_service::post` takes the completion handler by value this should actually not compile.

Comment: @bamboon You are right, this code is not correct, it's just to illustrate idea. Workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13158515/1599260

Comment: @Rost Ah thanks, that's a nice trick. I think in your typedef it should be `boost::packaged_task<bool()>`.

Comment: @bamboon It shall be `int` because actual future type is `int` here. I'm stick for Boost 1.51 where variadic template arguments version of `packaged_task` is not implemented yet. But of course, for Boost 1.53+ or well-implemented `std::packaged_task` it shall be `<int()>`.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use [boost::barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/barrier.html) as follow:

```
void thread_proc( boost::barrier& b ) {
    while( true ) {
        if( !ioservice.run_one() ) break; // io_service stopped
        b.wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I  might be able to use a barrier if I could have some sort of condition for each thread that checked whether there were any more handlers posted to each thread's queue. Is there such a thing?

Comment: You may have : `while( true ) { if( i_should_do_action() && !ioservice.run_once() ) break; b.wait(); }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. With the "work" object instantiated, the io_service won't ever be in a stopped state, will it? That is, will the call to io_service.run_once() ever return 0 in the setup above?

Comment: This is bad solution. It's not correct, not scalable, defeats the idea of multithreading. What if thread count is much less than parts of work to be done? I suppose it is. Each thread will execute one part of work and block until all other threads done. But why??? It must process another piece of work!

Comment: Also consider you have N threads and M parts of work. N < M. With your barrier you will stop waiting after N parts of work are done, but the rest M-N parts will not be done at the moment barrier is released!

Comment: @Rost I assume you want a solution that solve all problems of the world!? I have a solution for the question, in question we have N threads and N jobs and indicated that we want to do some jobs, wait for them to finish then start a new set of jobs! If it is strange to you, ask JohnDoe not me!!

Comment: No need for the flame war. I did envision there being a small number of threads (under 20) and many small tasks (10,000 or so), so it's likely that I'll need to use Rost's solution instead. However, BigBoss, I still don't know what to do with the fact that io_service.run_once() will probably never return 0 in my case. Or will it?

Comment: I don't want to start war either! this is stackoverflow and we are here to learn, I accept that @Rost version is much better for different number of threads and tasks, but this was the first thing that reach my mind in a second, a replacement for create/terminate threads. that's all! negative point is for answer that say something wrong according to the question, not something that can be better. never mind, if I were you I will select Rost solution, since it is better and we are here for best :)

Comment: @JonDoe `run_one` will return 0 after you destroy the `work` object

Answer (score 0):

Rost's method essentially works, but the boost::make_shared can not compile as is. The following is a working version (in vs2012):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/result_type.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

std::vector<boost::unique_future<void>> pending_data;
typedef boost::packaged_task<void> task_t;

boost::shared_ptr< boost::packaged_task<void> > pt(new boost::packaged_task<void> ([&,i](){...}));
boost::unique_future<void> result = pt->get_future();
pending_data.push_back(boost::move(result));
io_service.post(boost::bind(&task_t::operator(), pt));

boost::wait_for_all(pending_data.begin(), pending_data.end()); 
pending_data.clear();
```

It will not compile if use argument in the packaged_task typedef. This thread pool by asio and future method only saved 8% time compared with each loop create new thread methods.