# How do you post a boost packaged_task to an io_service in C++03?

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-asio, future

This is a follow-on from a previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146433/boostasio-thread-pool-implementation-for-occasionally-synchronized-tasks)), but I'm working on a multithreaded application and I would like to post a Boost packaged_task to a threaded io_service. I'm stuck using a C++03 compiler (so std::move is out), and the packaged_task is not copyable. I've tried wrapping it in a shared_ptr and passing that, and a lot of other things. Here is my current attempt and the subsequent compiler errors. Any idea how to get this to work?

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::thread_group threads;
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
for (int i = 0; i < maxNumThreads; ++i)
{
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
        &io_service));
}
std::vector<boost::shared_future<bool> > pending_data; // vector of futures

bool process_data(int,int){...}
...

for(int theTime = 0; theTime != totalScenarioTime; ++theTime)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numSmallTasks; ++i)
    {
        boost::packaged_task<bool> task(boost::bind(&process_data,i,theTime));
        boost::shared_future<bool> fut(task.get_future());
        pending_data.push_back(fut); // C++11 possible: (std::move(fut) when fut is a unique_future);
        io_service.post(task); // C++11 possible: (std::move(task));    
    }
    // After loop - wait until all futures are evaluated
    boost::wait_for_all(pending_data.begin(), pending_data.end()); 
    pending_data.clear();
}
```

This results in:

```
In file included from ../boostlibs/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:767:0,
             from ../boostlibs/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
             from ../boostlibs/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:19,
             from ../boostlibs/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
             from ../boostlibs/boost/asio.hpp:20,
             from ../main.cpp:13:
../boostlibs/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::io_service::post(const CompletionHandler&) [with CompletionHandler = boost::packaged_task<bool>]’:
../main.cpp:256:23:   instantiated from here
../boostlibs/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:95:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::packaged_task<bool>::packaged_task(const boost::packaged_task<bool>&)’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:95:67: note: candidates are:
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1372:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<R> >) [with R = bool]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1372:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::packaged_task<bool>’ to ‘boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<bool> >’
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1318:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task() [with R = bool]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1318:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1314:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task(boost::packaged_task<R>&) [with R = bool, boost::packaged_task<R> = boost::packaged_task<bool>]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1314:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::packaged_task<bool>’ to ‘boost::packaged_task<bool>&’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:95:26: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘T& boost::asio::detail::lvref(T) [with T = boost::packaged_task<bool>]’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:95:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::packaged_task<bool>::packaged_task(const boost::packaged_task<bool>&)’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:95:67: note: candidates are:
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1372:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<R> >) [with R = bool]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1372:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::packaged_task<bool>’ to ‘boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<bool> >’
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1318:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task() [with R = bool]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1318:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1314:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task(boost::packaged_task<R>&) [with R = bool, boost::packaged_task<R> = boost::packaged_task<bool>]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1314:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::packaged_task<bool>’ to ‘boost::packaged_task<bool>&’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:96:32: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘const T& boost::asio::detail::clvref(T) [with T = boost::packaged_task<bool>]’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:97:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::packaged_task<bool>::packaged_task(const boost::packaged_task<bool>&)’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:97:3: note: candidates are:
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1372:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<R> >) [with R = bool]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1372:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::packaged_task<bool>’ to ‘boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<bool> >’
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1318:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task() [with R = bool]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1318:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1314:9: note: boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task(boost::packaged_task<R>&) [with R = bool, boost::packaged_task<R> = boost::packaged_task<bool>]
../boostlibs/boost/thread/future.hpp:1314:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::packaged_task<bool>’ to ‘boost::packaged_task<bool>&’
../boostlibs/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.hpp:54:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::post(Handler) [with Handler = boost::packaged_task<bool>]’
```

Using boost::move(task) results in the two errors:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<bool> >) ()’
error: no match for call to ‘(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<bool> >) ()’
```

Comment: Which Boost version do you use?

Comment: In 1.50 boost::move(task) should work.

Comment: @Rost, @IgorR., I was using 1.49, now am using 1.51 and I still get the following error when using boost::move(task): `../boost_1_51_0/boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp:64:3: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::packaged_task<bool> >) ()’
` Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnDoe Strange thing, what compiler/version do you use?

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice you attempt to `post` it. `io_service::post` copies its arguments, so `move` wouldn't help. The only way is to allocate the task dynamically and pass its (shared)pointer - just like @Rost recommended.

Comment: @Rost gcc, 4.6.3, with and without the -std=c++03 flag, the error still occurs.

Comment: @JohnDoe Igor is right, I was disoriented by ability of `io_service::post` to take rvalues. But actually handler must be `CopyConstructible`, so `boost::packaged_task` cannot be posted directly or by moving :-( Sorry for inconvience.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`boost::packaged_task` supports `boost::move` since Boost version 1.50, see corresponding [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4521).

But the problem is that [`io_service::post`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html) completion handler parameter must be `CopyConstructible` as noted in [Asio handler requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html). Therefore `boost::packaged_task` cannot be posted directly or by moving. (Thanks to [Igor R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759253/igor-r) for this issue).

There is workaround using pointers, e.g. you could wrap `boost::packaged_task` with `boost::shared_ptr` and bind it to `operator()`:

```
 typedef boost::packaged_task<bool> task_t;
 boost::shared_ptr<task_t> task = boost::make_shared<task_t>(
    boost::bind(&process_data, i, theTime));

 io_service.post(boost::bind(&task_t::operator(), task));
```

Comment: your work-around of binding operator() to the shared pointer worked. Thanks so much for your help with this!

Comment: I would be very interested to know how this fairs for people using VC++10. While shared packaged-tasks seems to work fine on posix (mac clang and linux gcc), I get very strange errors on windows --> 'member function already defined or declared'

Comment: @BenJ I've just compiled this code on VC2010 using Boost 1.53 and it compiles and works OK (except for C4913 warning in future.hpp but this is known Boost issue). Could you please post your actual code?

Comment: Thanks Rost, yes, this was my mistake. I'm unfortunately having to use boost 1_49 which I've discovered is very buggy when it comes to packaged_tasks and shared_futures and even more so if c++11 compilation is enabled. These issues seem to have been fixed in later versions of boost